# Chaos in musician's program

Tags: rebus

This is a riddle in a form of rebus.
The answer is an English noun, and the hint is in the title.

`D#[]`

Hint #1:

> The musician is from the Europe

Hint #1A:

> There's an alternative way of naming musical notes with sharps, commonly used in Europe

Hint #2:

> He's a piano player, but writes his programs using a different kind of keyboard

Hint #2A:

> The 'program' word is used very deliberately. The musician is also a PC-charmer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm mostly just putting together things other people have found, but I think the answer we're looking for is

> DISARRAY

because

> D sharp can be called "Dis", and [] in various programming languages indicates an *array*. The connection with the title is obvious.

Comment: ah, *facepalm* yeah you probably got it

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Can I mark more than one solution as an answer?

Comment: (i was going on the wrong track as i thought the answer was a musician, my bad at reading)

Comment: @SolutusImmensus No

Comment: Sorry about that :(

Comment: Daaaamn! well done :)

Comment: @thecoder16 I don't think the problem was your reading. One of the hints *says* it's a musician.

Answer (score 2):

Don't have the answer but I have some suggestions

> I think pronouncing #=sharp would be too easy, maybe "hash" instead, that would be dash[], I think of "dashboard" but I don't see why []=board. 
>  then I thought about something else, you say he uses a keyboard but not a piano keyboard, maybe a computer keyboard. In this case [] is the syntax for an array in some programming languages but I can't get anything in that direction :(

Édit

> also D# is equivalent to Eflat (Eb), maybe search in that direction. In Europe D is ré and E is Mi (maybe it is only true for "Latin" country though). I found out that Mib is something related to networks, it seems there're 2 types of objects in MIB hierarchy: scalar and tabular, that would stick with the array

Comment: You're correct with the keyboard and interpretation of `[]` part

Comment: @SolutusImmensus did an edit, maybe I found something else :)

Answer (score 1):

About hints 1 and 1A:

> D-sharp can be referred to as Dis in Germany according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_note#Accidentals

So

> Disboard - discord? Consistent with the keyboard hint, gamers use keyboards

Comment: You're correct about the first part of the rebus.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it Franz Schubert? He is European and used different keyboards.

Comment: You're going the wrong direction with this. Said musician could be anyone, as long as they know basics of the music theory.